# How to use method in shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I have managed to configure, compile, and install some C source code into a Linux machine.

Now I know that my library (say `mylib.so`) is available at `/usr/local/bin`

I would like to write my C program with a main in it, that will access one of the methods in `mylib.so` that returns a struct defined in there.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: @ChrisMaes It shows how to do that with a method that returns `void`. My method returns a struct that is also defined in the library. Other thing I don't get is how will I know if the header file has defined the method I want to invoke as `extern`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should give you the result:

```
gcc -o prog prog.o -L/usr/local/bin -mylib
```

Comment: You missed the `-L` in front of /usr/local/bin  `$ gcc -o myprog myprog.c  -L/home/newhall/lib -lmine`

Comment: I thing the line should be:  gcc ${CCParms} -c prog.c -o prog.o -I. -Ipathtolibheaderfile  Then gcc ({LNparms} prog.o -o prog -L/usr/local/bin -lmy

Comment: Definitely needs `-L`, I removed it while editing the post. Thanks for pointing it out.